# Stuck with MySQL and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some stats. Example:

```
date        userId  attempts  good  bad
2010-08-23  1       5         4     1
2010-08-23  2       10        6     4
2010-08-23  3       6         3     3
2010-08-23  4       8         2     6
```

Each user has to do something, and the outcome is either good or bad. I'd like to find out what the *relative* score is for each user, compared to the other users *on that day*. Example:

User 1 made 5 attempts, and 4 of those were good. So `4 / 5 = 80%` of his attempts were good. For the other users that day it was 60%, 50% and 25%. So the relative score of successful attempts for user 1 on that day is `80 / (80 + 60 + 50 + 25) ≈ 37%`.

But I'm stuck at this point:

```
SELECT
  date,
  userId,
  ( (good / attempts) / x ) * 100 AS score_good
  ( (bad / attempts) / y ) * 100 AS score_bad
FROM stats
GROUP BY date, userId -- ?
```

Where **x** is the sum of all the `(good / attempts)` for that day, and **y** is the sum of all the `(bad / attempts)` for the same day. Can this be done in the same query?

I'd like the result to be e.g.

```
date        userId  score_good
2010-08-23  1       37%
2010-08-23  2       28% (60 / (80 + 60 + 50 + 25))
etc
```

Or:

```
userId   score_good_total
1        ...
```

Where `score_good_total` would be the sum of all the `score_good` scores, divided by the amount of days.

I can replace x and y with a subquery, but that doesn't seem they way to go, and will probably cause too much of a load when I want the data grouped by month or totals scores for all the available dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pulls out a bit of SQL-fu but it's perfectly doable in a very simple query.

```
// this would be the working query
SELECT 
   *,
   @score := good / attempts * 100 AS score,
   @t_score := (SELECT SUM(good / attempts * 100) FROM stats) as t_score ,
   @score / @t_score as relative_score_good
FROM stats
```

Bellow I you can use the values I used to replicate and play with the results.

The things to notice here are the **inside** sub-query thats an [`uncorrelated scalar subquery`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/subquery-restrictions.html) and will, therefore, only run once for all rows (just run the query with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to see that there are really only two queries here.

And the second thing to notice (**and the really important one!)** are the [**`user defined variables`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) that are written as `@variable`.

---

For replication purposes you can rebuild the sample table with these two commands (it's always nice if you can give the SQL to generate the demo values to the community).

```
// create the demo table
CREATE TABLE `test`.`stats` (
   `date` DATE NOT NULL ,
   `id` INT NOT NULL ,
   `attempts` INT NOT NULL ,
   `good` INT NOT NULL ,
   `bad` INT NOT NULL ,
   INDEX ( `id` , `attempts` , `good` , `bad` ) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM

// inject some values
INSERT INTO `test`.`stats` (`date`,`id`,`attempts` ,`good` ,`bad`)
VALUES 
   ('2010-08-23', '1', '5', '4', '1'), 
   ('2010-08-23', '2', '10', '6', '4'), 
   ('2010-08-23', '3', '6', '3', '3'), 
   ('2010-08-23', '4', '8', '2', '6');
```

Hope it helps! Saw the question just as I was leaving the office and though someone would beat me to it. Cinema and 4 hours latter and no answers yet, hurray! ;)

Comment: But won't the optimizer do something like this anyway for him if he just puts "SELECT SUM(good / attempts * 100) FROM stats" directly into his query?

Comment: Thanks, learned a few more things about MySQL here :) I finally decided to store a bit more data in the tables though, in the end that made it a lot easier to get the data I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a better way than the subquery, as any creative way to do this will have to sum all the rows anyway.  The optimizer should make your subqueries pretty well-performing, and it certainly is simple.

If you indeed need better performance, you'll have to run a separate job that saves all the "daily total" scores in another table, since they don't change once the day is done.  Then you can change your query to calculate it only if it is today; otherwise, use the data in said "daily total scores" table.